# SQL Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query causes the following error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Item_insupd, Line 17
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Query:

```
INSERT INTO [Total_Database].[dbo].[Item]
    (
        ItemID, 
        ItemNo,
        ItemDescription,
        Notes,
        StandardCost,
        SalesGLAccountID,
        ItemTypeID,
        Backorderable
    ) 
 (
    SELECT  [nr],
            [nr],
            [Latijn]+' '+[Subgroep]+' '+CAST([nr] as VARCHAR(255)),
            [NL]+' '+[Vorm]+' '+[Kenmerk]+' '+[Hoogte],[Inkoopprijs],
            (4),
            (case when [Productgroep]='PB' then 1 else 5 end),
            (1) 
    FROM    [ACCESDATA].[dbo].[Planten]
 );
```

I suspect this to happen because my subquery does not contain a `WHERE`, unfortunately I do not know how to construct a correct `WHERE` clause.

Comment: `INSERT..SELECT` doesn't have parenthesis around the `SELECT`.  The parenthesis make it a subquery, which is out of place there.

Comment: @RBarryYoung That could be a good answer, if it was an answer.

Comment: @GolezTrol You're right, I added it as an answer.

Comment: @Ben, do you have a trigger on this table?

Comment: @RBarryYoung : Unfortunately it's not a correct answer. Using/not using parenthesis makes no difference in SQLServer. Unless you meant different RDMS...

Comment: @Ben : Can you post your stored procedure (Procedure Item_insupd) ? I suspect you incorrectly identified error line...

Comment: @a1ex07 Yep.  Deleted.

Comment: @a1ex07 the trigger: http://pastebin.com/trF85RHq

Comment: I now suspect that `[ACCESDATA].[dbo].[Planten]` is a view or table-valued function that has the misbehaving subquery.

Comment: Right.  A trigger, that could easily be the problem.

Comment: @Ben : The trigger is quite large, but Roman Pekar's answer seems to make sense to me . I'd try disabling it first, run your insert, make sure it works, then try fixing the problem identified by Roman Pekar. Side note : do you realize that `ROLLBACK`s after `RAISERROR` never executed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the problem is in this string (line 26 in your [code](http://pastebin.com/trF85RHq)):

```
IF NOT (EXISTS (SELECT G.GLAccountID FROM GLAccnt G INNER JOIN Inserted I ON G.GLAccountID = I.SalesGLAccountID))
OR ((SELECT I.COGSGLAccountID FROM Inserted I) IS NOT NULL) AND NOT (EXISTS (SELECT G.GLAccountID FROM GLAccnt G INNER JOIN Inserted I ON G.GLAccountID = I.COGSGLAccountID))
```

It looks like `(SELECT I.COGSGLAccountID FROM Inserted I)` return more than one row, so you're getting an error.

You're treating `inserted` as a one row table (for example, you're getting parameters from it like `SELECT @ItemNo = I.ItemNo, @ItemDescription = I.ItemDescription FROM Inserted I`, but `inserted` table can have more than one row. So in your case I think you have 3 options - check that there's only 1 row in inserted, rewrite trigger as set-based, or use cursor.

Here's [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eec6d/6) with somewhat similar example.

Comment: Disabling the trigger did the job. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you really only want to insert one row, then You just add `Where` at the end, followed by some predicate (logical statement) that will be true for only one row in the table the query is reading from.

```
INSERT INTO [Total_Database].[dbo].[Item](ItemID,
    ItemNo,ItemDescription,Notes,StandardCost,SalesGLAccountID,
     ItemTypeID,Backorderable) 
SELECT  [nr],[nr],[Latijn]+' '+[Subgroep]+' '+CAST([nr] as VARCHAR(255)),
            [NL]+' '+[Vorm]+' '+[Kenmerk]+' '+[Hoogte],[Inkoopprijs],(4),
           (case when [Productgroep]='PB' then 1 else 5 end),(1) 
FROM  [ACCESDATA].[dbo].[Planten]
Where [SomeColumnName] = [some Value];
```

... but when performing an Insert using a select to generate the rows to be inserted, you just type the Select statement instead of the `Values()` clause, without surrounding parentheses.  I think that because you had the surrounding parentheses, the query processor assumed you wanted that to be a single value.  Do you want to only insert one row of data? or a whole set of data rows ?

Comment: I like a whole set, i know that the following works: WHERE [nr] = 'somenumber'; But if i remove the WHERE and execute the query without or with the parentheses i will get the same error.

Comment: @Ben,  That is not consistent with standard SQL,  An Insert should work just fine with a Select that returns multiple rows.  Please show the exact SQL you are using, without the Where clause, that you are experiencing the error with...  Unless your error is coming from some trigger on this table that is attempting to do something into another table using a subquery with this data?

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO [Total_Database].[dbo].[Item]
    (
        ItemID, 
        ItemNo,
        ItemDescription,
        Notes,
        StandardCost,
        SalesGLAccountID,
        ItemTypeID,
        Backorderable
    ) IN
 (
    SELECT  [nr],
            [nr],
            [Latijn]+' '+[Subgroep]+' '+CAST([nr] as VARCHAR(255)),
            [NL]+' '+[Vorm]+' '+[Kenmerk]+' '+[Hoogte],[Inkoopprijs],
            (4),
            (case when [Productgroep]='PB' then 1 else 5 end),
            (1) 
    FROM    [ACCESDATA].[dbo].[Planten]
 );
```

Comment: add IN before the select then it can select the multible values.