# sp error: subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server

Here is Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetMarkdownPlan]
    @MarkdownPlanDate   VARCHAR(10),
    @Memo               VARCHAR(100)

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

DECLARE @ItemType   VARCHAR(4)
SET @ItemType = (SELECT ItemType FROM tblMarkDownPlan 
            WHERE   MarkdownPlanDate    >= CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, @MarkdownPlanDate)
                AND MarkdownPlanDate    < CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, @MarkdownPlanDate) + 1
                AND Memo = @Memo);

BEGIN
IF @ItemType = '0010' -- itemcode
BEGIN
    SELECT  mdp.Itemcode,
            SectionCode,
            ColorID ='',
            SizeDCode ='',
            CurrentPrice,       
            MarkDownPrice

FROM  tblMarkDownPlan mdp LEFT OUTER JOIN tblMarkDownPlanSection mdps ON (mdp.MarkdownPlanDate = mdps.MarkdownPlanDate AND mdp.Itemcode = mdps.Itemcode AND mdp.Memo = mdps.Memo)
WHERE   mdp.MarkdownPlanDate        >= CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, @MarkdownPlanDate)
        AND mdp.MarkdownPlanDate            < CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, @MarkdownPlanDate) + 1
        AND mdp.Memo                = @Memo 
        AND mdp.ItemType = '0010'       
END
ELSE  

SELECT  mdp.Itemcode,
        SectionCode,
        ColorID ,
        SizeDCode ,
        CurrentPrice,       
        MarkDownPrice

FROM    tblMarkDownPlan mdp LEFT OUTER JOIN tblMarkDownPlanSectionSKU mdpsku ON (mdp.MarkdownPlanDate = mdpsku.MarkdownPlanDate AND mdp.Itemcode = mdpsku.Itemcode AND mdp.Memo = mdpsku.Memo)
WHERE   mdp.MarkdownPlanDate        >= CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, @MarkdownPlanDate)
        AND mdp.MarkdownPlanDate    < CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, @MarkdownPlanDate) + 1
        AND mdp.Memo                = @Memo
        AND mdp.ItemType != '0010'

END
```

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Do you have any good ideas?

Comment: `SELECT ItemType FROM tblMarkDownPlan` instead of that use `SELECT top 1 ItemType FROM tblMarkDownPlan`

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Subquery returned more than 1 value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336107/sql-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetMarkdownPlan]
    @MarkdownPlanDate   VARCHAR(10),
    @Memo               VARCHAR(100)

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

--DECLARE @ItemType   VARCHAR(4)
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ItemType') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #ItemType

CREATE TABLE #ItemType (ItemType VARCHAR(4));

INSERT INTO #ItemType 
SELECT ItemType FROM tblMarkDownPlan 
            WHERE   MarkdownPlanDate    >= CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, @MarkdownPlanDate)
                AND MarkdownPlanDate    < CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, @MarkdownPlanDate) + 1
                AND Memo = @Memo;

BEGIN
--IF @ItemType = '0010' -- itemcode
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #ItemType WHERE ItemType = '0010') -- itemcode
BEGIN
    SELECT  mdp.Itemcode,
            SectionCode,
            ColorID ='',
            SizeDCode ='',
            CurrentPrice,       
            MarkDownPrice

FROM  tblMarkDownPlan mdp LEFT OUTER JOIN tblMarkDownPlanSection mdps ON (mdp.MarkdownPlanDate = mdps.MarkdownPlanDate AND mdp.Itemcode = mdps.Itemcode AND mdp.Memo = mdps.Memo)
WHERE   mdp.MarkdownPlanDate        >= CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, @MarkdownPlanDate)
        AND mdp.MarkdownPlanDate            < CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, @MarkdownPlanDate) + 1
        AND mdp.Memo                = @Memo 
        AND mdp.ItemType = '0010'       
END
ELSE  

SELECT  mdp.Itemcode,
        SectionCode,
        ColorID ,
        SizeDCode ,
        CurrentPrice,       
        MarkDownPrice

FROM    tblMarkDownPlan mdp LEFT OUTER JOIN tblMarkDownPlanSectionSKU mdpsku ON (mdp.MarkdownPlanDate = mdpsku.MarkdownPlanDate AND mdp.Itemcode = mdpsku.Itemcode AND mdp.Memo = mdpsku.Memo)
WHERE   mdp.MarkdownPlanDate        >= CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, @MarkdownPlanDate)
        AND mdp.MarkdownPlanDate    < CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, @MarkdownPlanDate) + 1
        AND mdp.Memo                = @Memo
        AND mdp.ItemType != '0010'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ItemType') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #ItemType

END
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only one subquery, so that's the one that returns more than one item.

You could easily get around that by getting the first item:

```
SET @ItemType = (SELECT TOP 1 ItemType ...
```

However, you should consider *why* the subquery returns more than one item, and it it returns the correct items.

Comment: @gitstar: Then you have to rewrite the code. You can't store multiple values in a `varchar` value. If you want to loop through multiple items types you could use a table variable.

Comment: sir, excuse me, but can you write the simple sample to me?

Comment: @gitstar: What is it that you want to do with the different values?